# How can I combine the Properties of two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I have made a for loop that makes dots. Now I want to color them in a specific way. Like the first 200 are black and the next 326 are blue. I already managed that, but now I have so many rows of code and I wonder if there is a cleaner way to do it. For example make an array for the colors and then make an array for the values?

```
let circleColor = 'Lavender ';
const secondColor = 'burlyWood ';
const numberFirstColor = 493;
const numberSecondColor = numberFirstColor+578;
for (let i = 0; i < circleCount; i++) {
if (i > numberFirstColor) circleColor = secondColor;
if ( i > numberSecondColor) circleColor= thirdColor;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could keep an array of objects, then iterate over that:

```
 for(const { color, count } of [{ color: "Lavender", count: 200 }, { color: "burlyWood", count: 326 } /*..*/]) {
   for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     circleColor = color;
     //...
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another, bit more functional way would be to generate an array and then populate it with colors:

```
Array(circleCount)
  .fill()
  .map((_, idx) => idx < numberFirstColor ? circleColor : secondColor);
```

Then you can iterate over you array and get the color for your item.